# How does charge flow inside the thickness of parallel plate of a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, capacitance

In an uncharged capacitor current enters through one plate, accumulates on its bottom surface (which means positive charges accumulate)  and then due to repulsion repels the positive charges on the second plate and hence the current flow maintains.
But I want to know when the current enters the first plate, how does it flow inside that plate? Does it flow perpendicular to the area? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the current enters the first plate , how does it flow inside that plate

I refer you to the excellent illustrations of fig $9.3-9.6$ of this book$^2$ that show the direction of both the fields and the currents inside and around a discharging capacitor. (For a charging cap. reverse the arrows).

The conduction current density field essentially spreads radially outwards from the wire across the the plate  for the positive plate and towards the wire for the negative plate. It also decrease with radial distance.

[image: current density in plates-vector plots]
*fig 1. showing conduction current density field in the plates. The color represents field strength and decreases from orange to blue$^3$*

To quote the authors:

> Now if $J_D$ [the displacement current density] is a vector field without any curl, it can be made up, in the same way that electromagnetic field can be made of the fields of point charges, by superimposing radial currents flowing outward from point sources or in toward "sinks" (Fig. 9.6)

You also asked:

> Does it flow Perpendicular to the area

No. The conduction current stays in plate - so it flows parallel to the area.

---

*OP's query "Does it flow Perpendicular to the area ?" had earlier sent this answer on the tangent of displacement current. That earlier answer has now been relegated to this bottom*

When a capacitor is charging, the changing surface charge density of the plates leads to a changing electric field inside which leads to a changing magnetic field. This dynamic electromagnetic field is responsible for generating the current across the insulating gap in a capacitor. This current isn't like a normal conduction current through a wire.$^0$

Maxwell first theoretically discovered this current as the correction to Ampere's law. Its called the displacement current. Its unique among currents in that it doesn't involve charge carriers, and travels at the speed of light. In natural units$^1$ its (density) is given by

$$\frac {d\vec{E}}{dt}$$

As you can see its in the direction of the electric field and is therefore perpendicular to the cap's plates.

---

$^0$ During steady state too there's no conduction current through a capacitor.

$^1$$\epsilon_0=1$

$^2$ Purcell, Edward M.; Morin, David J. (2013). Electricity and Magnetism (3rd ed.). Cambridge University Press. ISBN 978-1-107-01402-2. [A google link to the same](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwign6CN1pzxAhWlyzgGHbamAToQFjAAegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fedisciplinas.usp.br%2Fpluginfile.php%2F5086475%2Fmod_folder%2Fcontent%2F0%2FExtras%2FElectricity%2520and%2520Magnetism%2520%255BPurcell-Morin%255DA.pdf%3Fforcedownload%3D1&usg=AOvVaw3FhtmXh-7kFT9oJLf3kAgo)

$^3$(for accessibility) i.e. radially outwards from the center of the images

Comment: "This dynamic electromagnetic field is responsible for generating the current across the insulating gap in a capacitor." There is no (conduction) current across the insulating gap in a capacitor. If you mean displacement current, you should say so.

Comment: @BobD I think I did 2nd para

Comment: Yes, but IMO the connection could be better. There is, in reality, no current across he insulating gap. But that's OK. You can phrase it as you wish.

Comment: He clearly said "uncharged capacitor", this is not a question about steady state.

Comment: @SeñorO hence the one line. Its not the premise of the question. I only mentioned it to imply there *never* really is a conduction current inside a cap steady or other wise

Comment: You never actually answered OPs question then

Comment: @SeñorO hope we are seeing the same answer...I have mentioned that the displacement current is perpendicular to the capacitor's surface. Also I moved the steady state condition to the footnote

Comment: @BobD I added a line. Hope the connection is clearer to future readers.

Comment: @lineage basically you answered that how does current flow between the plates . Actually no current flows between the plates ,its only the field lines between the plate  (current can't flow through air gap ,as air has infinite resistance thats why charges accumulate on plates of capacitors).Current flows in circuit as lower plate looses positive charge due to repulsion as to maintain field=0 inside conducting plates  .But i clearly mentioned in the question ,that i wanted to know how current flows inside the thickness of a particular plate ,not between the plates ! .

Comment: you may edit your answer

Comment: @SeñorO *You never actually answered OPs question then* With the OP's comment, I realised that query about the current *in* the plate. If thats what you had meant (though u didn't say so in your critique), a belated thanks.

Comment: @RaghavMadan *Actually no current flows between the plates ,its only the field lines between the plate* No it does. Its called the displcement current.  Even though its just field changing, there is a current. Across the gap. Without the charges. With the dimensions and all the properties of a good old current. Infact, they generate their own magnetic field (though that sums to zero on the whole). Just because the conduction current can't cross the gap doesn't mean there is no *current*.

Comment: @lineage  Ok thanks . Respect for your hardwork in updating and writing such a nice answer

Comment: @lineage this question will  be available for a bounty tomorrow .,WIll definitely award you with +50

Comment: @RaghavMadan glad to help